# Can't simulate a paste event with image data

Tags: javascript, paste

I want to automate a process and create a paste event programmatically with content from the clipboard (the clipboard permission is granted).

I am using chrome, here's my code

```js
setTimeout(async function () {

    // create image url
    const item = (await navigator.clipboard.read())[0]
    const data = await item.getType('image/png')
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(data)
    
    // create paste event
    const pasteEvent = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        dataType: 'image/png',
        data: url
    })

    // dispatch Event
    document.dispatchEvent(pasteEvent)

}, 2000)
```

*(the timeout here is used to focus on the document before the script run)*

Unfortunately this code produces no error, but the paste event doesn't seem to do anything either, it should update the interface but it doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the type is image/png? Also note that this won't work here on SO snippets.

Comment: I;d use the `for of` method shown in [the example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem/getType)

Answer (score 1):

I finally made my code work using the `DataTransfer` API.
Thanks to anyone that helped me.

```js
const clipboardItems = await navigator.clipboard.read()
const firstItem = clipboardItems[0]

try { // if there is an image
  const blob = await firstItem.getType('image/png')
  const file = new File([blob], 'image.png', {type: 'image/png'})

  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
  dataTransfer.items.add(file)

  const pasteEvent = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clipboardData: dataTransfer,
  })


  document.dispatchEvent(pasteEvent)
}
catch (e) {
    /* ignore */
}
```